# Passing parameter to custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, axios

There is lot of documentation about the hooks, but I don't seem to understand them well enough.

**Code**

```
const App = () => {
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState(null);

const fetchMarkers = async () => {
const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/markers`);
setMarkers(res.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
fetchMarkers();
}, []);

useInterval(() => {
fetchMarkers();
}, 10000);
}
```

I've made a custom hook which returns an object, I can call it like this:

```
const location = useGeoLocation();
```

I would like to add markers as parameter to useGeoLocation hook. This can be achieved easily just by calling the function on code and adding markers.

**Objective**

My goal is to make sure that markers contains some value before calling useGeoLocation. Right now, geoLocation hooks parameter returns value of null, because application didn't have time to fetchMarkers and update the state.

**I've tried**

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
  if (markers) {
  const location = useGeoLocation(markers);
  }
```

But of course, like stated in [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), hooks can't be used conditionally.

**UPDATED 10.1.2022 - useGeoLocation hook**

Here I'm fetching users location. On success, I will compare users location to an array of markers & find the closest one to user.
On error, I will return only a predefined location.

This doesn't work because onSuccess is executed before there is any data in markers(null). I'm not sure how to use if - else statement here, because I'm also using useEffect & useState.

Can someone help?

```
const useGeoLocation = (markers) => {

const [location, setLocation] = useState({
loaded: false,
coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
 });

const onSuccess = (location) => {
// User location succesfully fetched, converting data format.
const targetPoint = turf.point([
  location.coords.latitude,
  location.coords.longitude,
]);

// Fetching data from markers parameter and converting data format.
var arr = [];
markers.map((marker) => arr.push(turf.point(marker.location)));
var points2 = turf.featureCollection(arr);

// Calculating which marker is nearest to targetPoint.
var nearest = turf.nearestPoint(targetPoint, points2);

// Setting location of nearest marker to usestate.
setLocation({
  loaded: true,
  coordinates: {
    lat: nearest.geometry.coordinates[0],
    lng: nearest.geometry.coordinates[1],
  },
});
};

const onError = () => {
setLocation({
  loaded: true,
  coordinates: {
    lat: 65.024335,
    lng: 27.277089,
  },
  });
  };

useEffect(() => {
if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
  onError();
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}, []);

return location;
};
```

Comment: hooks can't be used conditionally. Just do `useGeoLocation(markers)`, use the `if...else` condition statement inside the custom hook. E.g. `if(!markers) return someFallback; // do something with makers`

Comment: can you share the geoLocation hook code?

Comment: I shared useGeoLocation hook code to my question, please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Add markers in the dependency array of useEffect hook of useGeoLocation and call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError) if the markers are available and in the else part you can call setLocation().

```
const useGeoLocation = (markers) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    loaded: false,
    coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
  });

  
  useEffect(() => {
      if (markers) {
          if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
            onError();
          }
      
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
      } else {
        setLocation();
      }
  }, [markers]);

  return location;
};
```